# Cloo not working in Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: cloo

When I try to run Clootils in Windows 8.1 Pro, it crashes. Event Viewer has this error:

```
Faulting application name: Clootils.exe, version: 0.9.1.0, time stamp: 0x4ebef909
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17278, time stamp: 0x53eebd22
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f0d6c
Faulting process id: 0x16f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cff45c01ece0ed
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Ron\Documents\CodeLibs\Cloo0.9.1\Clootils\bin\Release\Clootils.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 3fc2e99c-604f-11e4-be90-14feb598fbe1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

If I try to run it in Debug configuration in VS 2013, it dies the same way. I put a break on line 70 in MainForm.cs:

```
object[] availablePlatforms = new object[ComputePlatform.Platforms.Count];
```

and then it stops there; but if I try to Step Into or Step Over, it dies with the same error as above in Event Viewer.
I upgraded the projects to .NET 4.5 and rebuilt, but to no avail: same error.

I have "OpenCL 1.1 support for Intel Core processor family" installed.  My laptop is an i7 CPU.
My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M.

Clootils worked fine on the same hardware when it was running Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Intel OpenCL on my laptop must have been corrupted, because when I uninstalled and re-installed the latest version, the above problem disappeared.